# Spring calling method catches exception thrown by @async method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, concurrent.futures

TestController uses a TestService which has a spring @async asyncComp.getGood(s) method.  When the input string is not "good", an exception is thrown. TestController will get the exception and in the rest response, status 500 internal server error.
I could not find the exact code for my project but found some ideas about using CompletableFuture. In the answer area, I am posting what I wrote as a testing app which works the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test code which allows controller to get exception thrown by an asynchronous method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AsyncApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AsyncApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync()
@ComponentScan
public class SpringAsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {
    @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new CustomAsyncExceptionHandler();
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
   
    @Autowired
    TestService service; 
    
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() throws Exception {
        return service.getGood("bad");
        
    }
    
}
```

```
@Service
public class TestService {
    
    @Autowired
    AsyncComponent asyncComp;
    
    public String getGood(String s) throws Exception {
        
            CompletableFuture<String> result = asyncComp.getGood(s);
            return result.get();
        
    }
    

}
```

```
@Component
public class AsyncComponent {

    
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<String> getGood(String s) throws Exception {
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("good")) {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(s);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("test exception");
        }

    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.aaa</groupId>
    <artifactId>async</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Async</name>
    <description>async</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[image: rest call response]